# MacBook Air Locks up After Closing Lid: 20.04

Tags: 20.04, power-management, lid

Details:

- Power button must be depressed for 10 seconds to recover (reboot)
- Unsaved data is lost
- Lockup happens after several minutes of closure
- The battery drains during this lockup and the laptop gets fairly warm
- The screen and keyboard are both off during this lockup
- This is a recent dual boot installation of 20.04 and this issue has been present since day 1
- The computer is early 2015 vintage. Hardware details follow:

Model Name: MacBook Air

Model Identifier:   MacBookAir7,2

Processor Name:   Intel Core i5

Processor Speed:  1.6 GHz

Number of Processors: 1

Total Number of Cores:    2

L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB

L3 Cache: 3 MB

Memory:   8 GB

Boot ROM Version: MBA71.0166.B13

SMC Version (system): 2.27f2

Serial Number (system):   C1MPF6H4G944

Hardware UUID:    DAA74C19-D324-5D55-A03F-FAE4B3AAFA3B

Comment: There's an insufficient amount of information here to work with. Can you update the question to include *which model* of MacBook you're using and whether this is a recent development or something that has existed for a while. Can you also confirm your Ubuntu release, as I'm seeing both 20.04 and 12.04 described in the post 

Comment: My bad on any confusion. Thank you for helping me and I'm ready to assist. just let me know what to do next.